# How to make a process ring with fork and mkfifo?

Tags: c, linux, fork, child-process, fifo

Currently I'm learning C and I'd like to make a ring of n childs process with forks and pipes where n is a number entered in argument.  Each child could communicate with the next child in two directions like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKC0P.png):

```
p1 --->--- p2
   ---<---
||         ||
^v         ^v
||         ||
   --->---
p4 ---<--- p3
```

I tried to do it where each child send to the next child its pid or a message, but I don't get what I want for instance. When I run the program, I've got two issues:

- the first issue is that if I enter an argument over 5, I get the **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** error
- the second issue is that when a process sends its pid inside the ring, it seems to be the only one that reads it.

What's going wrong?

I'm not really comfortable with multiple fifos in a loop.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define MIN_PROC 2      // Nombre minimum de processus
#define MAX_PROC 20     // Nombre maximum de processus

int main (int argc,char ** argv)
 {
int n;  // Nombre de processus dans l'anneau

/* Lecture du paramètre */
if (argc<2 || (n = (int)strtol(argv[1],NULL,0))<MIN_PROC || n>MAX_PROC)
 {
    fprintf (stderr,"Usage : %s <nombre>\n"
                    "Avec <nombre> compris entre %d et %d.\n",
                    argv[0],MIN_PROC,MAX_PROC);
    exit(1);
 }
else
 {
    char tubes[2*n];
    pid_t   pid;
            // Réception du PID lors de fork()
    int     p[n][4];    // Place pour n paires de descripteurs (VLA)
    int     i,pos =0,k;          // Indice de boucle

    /* Indication du nombre de processus à engendrer */
    for (int i = 0; i < n*2; i++)
    {
        pos += sprintf(&tubes[pos],",tube%d",i);
    }
    printf("String is now:%s\n",tubes);
    printf ("Nombre de processus à engendrer : %d\n",n);

    /* Création des n tubes anonymes.             */
    /* On considère que l'appel réussit toujours. */
    for (k=0;k<n;k++){
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                p[k][i] = mkfifo(tubes[i],0666);

            } 
        }

    /* Génération des n processus fils, qui vont communiquer */
    /* entre eux. Le processus père reste en superviseur.    */
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid>0)
        {
            printf ("Création du processus fils #%d : PID %d\n",i,pid);
        }
        else if (!pid)
        {


            int     in[2];     /* Descripteurs d'entrée     */
            int     out[2];    /* Descripteurs de sortie    */
            int     data;   /* Donnée à émettre         */

            int     j;      /* Autre indice de boucle (puisque i reste */
                            /* de fait notre numéro de processus fils. */

            /* Temporisation pour que la boucle du processus père ait   */
            /* le temps de se terminer avant de commencer le traitement */
            sleep(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {   
                if (i%2 == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
                    {
                       in[i]= open(tubes[i],O_RDONLY);
                       out[i]= open(tubes[i],O_WRONLY); 
                    }

                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
                    {
                       in[i]= open(tubes[i],O_WRONLY);
                       out[i]= open(tubes[i],O_RDONLY); 
                    }
                }

            }

            /* Récupération des descripteurs adéquats */
            in[0]  = p[ i       ][0];
            out[0] = p[(i+1) % n][1];
            in[1]  = p[ i      ][2];
            out[1] = p[(i+1) % n][3];

            /* Fermeture des descripteurs inutiles */
            for (j=0;j<n;++j)
            {
                if (p[j][0] != in[0])  close(p[j][0]);
                if (p[j][1] != out[0]) close(p[j][1]);
                if (p[j][2] != in[1])  close(p[j][2]);
                if (p[j][3] != out[2]) close(p[j][3]);
            }

            /* Récupération et émission de notre PID */
            data = (int)getpid();
            printf ("Processus #%d : émission de %d\n",i,data);
            write (out[0],&data,sizeof data);
            close (out[0]);

            /* Réception de la donnée de l'autre processus */
            data = (int)getpid();
            read (in[0],&data,sizeof data);
            printf ("Processus #%d : réception de %d\n",i,data);
            close (in[0]);

            data = (int)getpid();
            printf ("Processus #%d : émission de %d\n",i,data);
            write (out[1],&data,sizeof data);
            close (out[1]);

            /* Réception de la donnée de l'autre processus */
            data = (int)getpid();
            read (in[1],&data,sizeof data);
            printf ("Processus #%d : réception de %d\n",i,data);
            close (in[1]);

            /* En fin de traitement, un break pour quitter la boucle */
            /* démarrée par le processus père.                       */
            break;
        }
        else perror ("Erreur à l'appel de fork()");
    }

    /* Si PID est non nul à l'issue de la boucle, c'est qu'on est  */
    /* toujours dans le processus père. On en profite pour faire n */
    /* wait() successifs pour attendre tous nos fils.              */
    if (pid>0)
    for (i=0;i<2*n;i++) {
        wait(NULL);
        unlink(tubes[i]);
    }
 }

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using `mkfifo()` rather than `pipe()`?  Your processes are all closely related, so pipes, which need no cleaning up, seem like a better choice than FIFOs, which do need cleaning up.  How are the processes going to decide when to communicate clockwise around the ring and when anticlockwise?  How are the processes going to detect whether there is input waiting on the clockwise input or anticlockwise input?  Things will lock up if any of the processes makes the wrong decision.  (Note that you should include the ASCII art image in the question as 'code', not as an external image.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @JonathanLeffler.i have already done it using pipe but now, in need to  better , i wanted to make the same program using named pipes

Comment: Your array of 'pipe' names is `char tubes[2*n];` — you actually need something like `char tubes[2*n][20];` so you've got space enough to write the different names. Your code probably crashes because you're writing out of bounds of that array. You should be getting shrieks of outrage from your compiler when you write `mkfifo(tubes[i],0666);` because you pass a `char` to a function that expects a `char *`. Pay attention to your compiler warnings — and make sure you've got the warning levels turned up. You're on Linux; you probably use GCC. I compile code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror …` etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fifo are less documented than anonymous pipes,i've searched all over the net an example of c prog that allows bidirectional communication between multiple processes and found nothing , that's why i'm having so issues

Comment: I've not yet worked out how your code connects to the pipes.  One problem is that a process blocks when opening a FIFO for reading until/unless there's a writer with the FIFO open for writing, and vice versa.  You have `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { if (i%2 == 0) { for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { in[i]= open(tubes[i],O_RDONLY); out[i]= open(tubes[i],O_WRONLY); } } else { for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { in[i]= open(tubes[i],O_WRONLY); out[i]= open(tubes[i],O_RDONLY); } } }` (which is clear as mud in a comment).  You have an outer loop on `i`, and two inner loops on a different `i`. That's confused.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, because i chose not to use O_NONBLOCK option, i found an algorithm that indicates that in order to avaoid blocking opening of the pipes, each odd numbered process should have its pipe opened first for reading and for writing after and  and for non odd numbered process, it's the opposite

Comment: Not using O_NONBLOCK is probably correct.  The indexing in the loops is probably not correct.  You need to take N=4, say, and work out which connections each process needs to make.  You need a factor of 2, and a `+ 1` in the indexing.  I assume you've fixed the issues with the FIFO names.

Comment: not yet ,i tried this after applying your suggested correction `p[i] = mkfifo(tubes[i], S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);` and i get the **assignment to expression with array type** error

Comment: As far as I can see, you have to split the connections into 'forward' and 'backward' around the loop.  P0 (zeroth child) needs to connect forward first, then connect backward; all other children need to connect backward first, then connect forward.  Although the order is arbitrary, when a child connects backward, it should open the read FIFO before the write FIFO; when it connects forward, it should open the write FIFO before the read FIFO.

Comment: Child process Pn (for n = 0; n < N; n++) connects forward to tube `T[(2n)%(2N)]` for writing, `T[(2n+1)%(2N)]` for reading; and connects backward to `T[(2n-2+2N)%(2N)]` for reading, and to `T[(2n-1+2N)%(2N)]` for writing.  The `+2N` terms ensure that the LHS of `%` is not negative.  This sequencing should ensure no blockage, I think.   I haven't coded it yet.

Comment: interesting way to do it,

Comment: In your code, you have an array `p` that records whether the FIFOs were created successfully or not — and you loop too enthusiastically creating the FIFOs (so later calls are bound to fail).  You later open the FIFOs, but overwrite the file descriptors recorded from `open` by the statuses returned by `mkfifo()`.  This is not conducive to happiness.

Comment: another silly issue,my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation that works.  It required some care to get the connections established, as outlined in comments and not repeated in this answer.  The writing sequence also has to match the open sequence:

- P0 will write forward, read forward, read backward, write backward.
- PN will read backward, write backward, write forward, read forward.

Note that the code with the children is basically synchronous — there is not much resequencing that can happen.  The [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) call simply ensures that startup messages are sequenced.  Only the reporting output may be messier if you drop it.

I've used my Standard Error Reporting package, [`"stderr.h"` and `stderr.c`](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq), to handle much of the messaging from the code. (At the moment, if you use `stderr.c`, you'll also need `kludge.h` and `kludge.c` from the same directory.)  The package has features that make it convenient (using `err_setlogopts()` to include the PID and micro-second timing but omit the program name, and `err_settimeformat()` to only print the time and not the date component of the information).

I also used a number of functions — I'm not clever enough to write the code in a single function.  Very often, for a simple parent-child relationship, I'll have a pair of functions `be_childish()` and `be_parental()` to encapsulate the work done by child and parent processes.  In this code, I didn't really need a separate parental function.

There are about 200 lines in the code below - including the blank lines and comments.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MIN_PROC 2
#define MAX_PROC 20

enum { MAX_TUBENAMELEN = 20 };
enum { MAX_MSGLEN = 256 };
enum Mode { M_WF, M_RF, M_WB, M_RB };

/*
**  You have to split the connections into 'forward' and 'backward'
**  around the loop.  P0 (zeroth child) needs to connect forward first,
**  then connect backward; all other children need to connect backward
**  first, then connect forward.  Although the order is arbitrary, when
**  a child connects backward, it should open the read FIFO before the
**  write FIFO; when it connects forward, it should open the write FIFO
**  before the read FIFO.
**
**  Child process Pn (for n = 0; n < N; n++) connects forward to tube
**  T[(2n)%(2N)] for writing, T[(2n+1)%(2N)] for reading; and connects
**  backward to T[(2n-2+2N)%(2N)] for reading, and to T[(2n-1+2N)%(2N)]
**  for writing.  The +2N terms ensure that the LHS of % is not
**  negative.  This sequencing should ensure no blockage
**
**  When it comes to reading and writing, the rules will be similar.
**  P0 will write forward, read forward, read backward, write backward.
**  PN will read backward, write backward, write forward, read forward.
*/

static inline int tube_index(int num, int max)
{
    int idx = (num + 2 * max) % (2 * max);
    return idx;
}

static int open_fifo(enum Mode mode, int max, int num, char tubes[][MAX_TUBENAMELEN])
{
    int fd;
    int idx = 0;
    switch (mode)
    {
    case M_WF: idx = tube_index(2 * num + 0, max); break;
    case M_RF: idx = tube_index(2 * num + 1, max); break;
    case M_RB: idx = tube_index(2 * num - 2, max); break;
    case M_WB: idx = tube_index(2 * num - 1, max); break;
    default: assert(0);
    }
    const char *fifoname = tubes[idx];
    int o_mode = O_RDONLY;
    if (mode == M_WF || mode == M_WB)
        o_mode = O_WRONLY;
    err_remark("Opening FIFO %s with mode %d\n", fifoname, o_mode);
    if ((fd = open(fifoname, o_mode)) < 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to open %s with mode %d: ", fifoname, o_mode);
    err_remark("Opened  FIFO %s with mode %d - fd %d\n", fifoname, o_mode, fd);
    return fd;
}

static inline void recv_info(int num, int fd)
{
    char buffer[MAX_MSGLEN];
    int nbytes;
    if ((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) <= 0)
        err_syserr("P%d failed to read anything on fd %d: ", num, fd);
    err_remark("P%d received %d bytes: [%.*s]\n", num, nbytes, nbytes, buffer);
}

static inline void send_info(int num, int fd, const char *dir)
{
    char buffer[MAX_MSGLEN];
    int buflen = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "P%d (PID %d) sent this message %s",
                    num, (int)getpid(), dir);
    int nbytes;
    if ((nbytes = write(fd, buffer, buflen)) != buflen)
        err_syserr("Failed to write properly on fd %d (%d vs %d wanted): ", fd, nbytes, buflen);
    err_remark("P%d sent %d bytes: [%.*s]\n", num, nbytes, nbytes, buffer);
}

static void be_childish(int max, int num, char tubes[][MAX_TUBENAMELEN])
{
    int wf;     /* Descriptor for writing forwards */
    int wb;     /* Descriptor for writing backwards */
    int rf;     /* Descriptor for reading forwards */
    int rb;     /* Descriptor for reading backwards */

    if (num == 0)
    {
        /* Child zero connects forwards then backwards */
        wf = open_fifo(M_WF, max, num, tubes);
        rf = open_fifo(M_RF, max, num, tubes);
        rb = open_fifo(M_RB, max, num, tubes);
        wb = open_fifo(M_WB, max, num, tubes);
        send_info(num, wf, "forwards");
        recv_info(num, rf);
        recv_info(num, rb);
        send_info(num, wb, "backwards");
    }
    else
    {
        /* Other children connect backwards then forwards */
        rb = open_fifo(M_RB, max, num, tubes);
        wb = open_fifo(M_WB, max, num, tubes);
        wf = open_fifo(M_WF, max, num, tubes);
        rf = open_fifo(M_RF, max, num, tubes);
        recv_info(num, rb);
        send_info(num, wb, "backwards");
        send_info(num, wf, "forwards");
        recv_info(num, rf);
    }

    close(wf);
    close(wb);
    close(rf);
    close(rb);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    err_setlogopts(ERR_NOARG0|ERR_PID|ERR_MICRO);
    err_settimeformat("%H:%M:%S");

    if (argc < 2 || (n = (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0)) < MIN_PROC || n > MAX_PROC)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s <nombre>\n"
                "Avec <nombre> compris entre %d et %d.\n",
                argv[0], MIN_PROC, MAX_PROC);
        exit(1);
    }

    char tubes[2 * n][MAX_TUBENAMELEN];
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t pids[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n * 2; i++)
    {
        snprintf(tubes[i], sizeof(tubes[i]), "tube%d", i);
        printf("Fifo %d: [%s]\n", i, tubes[i]);
    }

    printf("Nombre de processus à engendrer : %d\n", n);

    for (int k = 0; k < 2*n; k++)
    {
        printf("Create fifo: %s\n", tubes[k]);
        if (mkfifo(tubes[k], 0666) != 0)
            err_syserr("Failed to create FIFO %s: ", tubes[k]);
    }
    fflush(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid > 0)
        {
            pids[i] = pid;
            err_remark("Création du processus fils #%d : PID %d\n", i, (int)pid);
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            usleep((i + 1) * 100000);   // Tenths of a second
            err_remark("Child process #%d (PID %d) at work\n", i, (int)getpid());
            be_childish(n, i, tubes);
            int status = (i + 1) * 16;
            err_remark("Child process #%d (PID %d) exiting with status 0x%.2X\n", i, (int)getpid(), status);
            exit(status);
        }
        else
        {
            err_sysrem("Failed to fork child %d: ", i);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                err_remark("Killing %d\n", pids[j]);
                kill(SIGTERM, pids[j]);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++)
                unlink(tubes[j]);
            err_error("Terminating!\n");
        }
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        err_remark("Child %d died with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);

    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++)
        unlink(tubes[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Fifo 0: [tube0]
Fifo 1: [tube1]
Fifo 2: [tube2]
Fifo 3: [tube3]
Fifo 4: [tube4]
Fifo 5: [tube5]
Nombre de processus à engendrer : 3
Create fifo: tube0
Create fifo: tube1
Create fifo: tube2
Create fifo: tube3
Create fifo: tube4
Create fifo: tube5
16:19:57.312293 - pid=89807: Création du processus fils #0 : PID 89810
16:19:57.314294 - pid=89807: Création du processus fils #1 : PID 89811
16:19:57.314500 - pid=89807: Création du processus fils #2 : PID 89812
16:19:57.413772 - pid=89810: Child process #0 (PID 89810) at work
16:19:57.415148 - pid=89810: Opening FIFO tube0 with mode 1
16:19:57.515290 - pid=89811: Child process #1 (PID 89811) at work
16:19:57.515558 - pid=89811: Opening FIFO tube0 with mode 0
16:19:57.515771 - pid=89810: Opened  FIFO tube0 with mode 1 - fd 3
16:19:57.515788 - pid=89810: Opening FIFO tube1 with mode 0
16:19:57.515764 - pid=89811: Opened  FIFO tube0 with mode 0 - fd 3
16:19:57.515883 - pid=89811: Opening FIFO tube1 with mode 1
16:19:57.516011 - pid=89810: Opened  FIFO tube1 with mode 0 - fd 4
16:19:57.516020 - pid=89810: Opening FIFO tube4 with mode 0
16:19:57.516010 - pid=89811: Opened  FIFO tube1 with mode 1 - fd 4
16:19:57.516120 - pid=89811: Opening FIFO tube2 with mode 1
16:19:57.615230 - pid=89812: Child process #2 (PID 89812) at work
16:19:57.615451 - pid=89812: Opening FIFO tube2 with mode 0
16:19:57.615582 - pid=89812: Opened  FIFO tube2 with mode 0 - fd 3
16:19:57.615593 - pid=89811: Opened  FIFO tube2 with mode 1 - fd 5
16:19:57.615678 - pid=89812: Opening FIFO tube3 with mode 1
16:19:57.615747 - pid=89811: Opening FIFO tube3 with mode 0
16:19:57.615852 - pid=89811: Opened  FIFO tube3 with mode 0 - fd 6
16:19:57.615881 - pid=89812: Opened  FIFO tube3 with mode 1 - fd 4
16:19:57.615986 - pid=89812: Opening FIFO tube4 with mode 1
16:19:57.616078 - pid=89810: Opened  FIFO tube4 with mode 0 - fd 5
16:19:57.616090 - pid=89810: Opening FIFO tube5 with mode 1
16:19:57.616071 - pid=89812: Opened  FIFO tube4 with mode 1 - fd 5
16:19:57.616153 - pid=89812: Opening FIFO tube5 with mode 0
16:19:57.616240 - pid=89810: Opened  FIFO tube5 with mode 1 - fd 6
16:19:57.616277 - pid=89810: P0 sent 41 bytes: [P0 (PID 89810) sent this message forwards]
16:19:57.616236 - pid=89812: Opened  FIFO tube5 with mode 0 - fd 6
16:19:57.616312 - pid=89811: P1 received 41 bytes: [P0 (PID 89810) sent this message forwards]
16:19:57.616444 - pid=89810: P0 received 42 bytes: [P1 (PID 89811) sent this message backwards]
16:19:57.616437 - pid=89811: P1 sent 42 bytes: [P1 (PID 89811) sent this message backwards]
16:19:57.616530 - pid=89811: P1 sent 41 bytes: [P1 (PID 89811) sent this message forwards]
16:19:57.616535 - pid=89812: P2 received 41 bytes: [P1 (PID 89811) sent this message forwards]
16:19:57.616660 - pid=89812: P2 sent 42 bytes: [P2 (PID 89812) sent this message backwards]
16:19:57.616665 - pid=89811: P1 received 42 bytes: [P2 (PID 89812) sent this message backwards]
16:19:57.616772 - pid=89812: P2 sent 41 bytes: [P2 (PID 89812) sent this message forwards]
16:19:57.616881 - pid=89810: P0 received 41 bytes: [P2 (PID 89812) sent this message forwards]
16:19:57.616893 - pid=89810: P0 sent 42 bytes: [P0 (PID 89810) sent this message backwards]
16:19:57.616817 - pid=89811: Child process #1 (PID 89811) exiting with status 0x20
16:19:57.617243 - pid=89810: Child process #0 (PID 89810) exiting with status 0x10
16:19:57.617501 - pid=89812: P2 received 42 bytes: [P0 (PID 89810) sent this message backwards]
16:19:57.617726 - pid=89807: Child 89811 died with status 0x2000
16:19:57.618114 - pid=89812: Child process #2 (PID 89812) exiting with status 0x30
16:19:57.618313 - pid=89807: Child 89810 died with status 0x1000
16:19:57.618635 - pid=89807: Child 89812 died with status 0x3000
```

You can find this code at [GitHub](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-4319-0158).

Comment: Amazing work ,Thank you very much Jonathan.And if i may ask, why did you say that not using O_NONBLOCK was correct

Comment: Well, it wasn't so much 'incorrect' as 'unnecessary' — witness the code with no `O_NONBLOCK` references anywhere.  There are certainly ways to use it, but you have to be aware that you may get 'errors' from `read()` calls when there is no data waiting.  Using O_NONBLOCK makes life more complicated.  So would using O_RDWR; that also achieves the 'does not block on `open()`' effect for FIFOs.

Comment: The code studiously stays away from testing which read channels are ready for reading, and such refinements.  That requires the use of `select()` or `poll()` and is a whole separate bag of worms.  If you were to test that, rather than using the 'one-shot and done' approach shown, you'd need quite a lot more code.